# Compute time diffs between each entry in one dataframe and all entries in another - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Again, I have 2 data frames consisting of times. I'd like to find the **delta** time between **each** df1 Stop Time and **every** df2 Start Time. If the Start Time in df2 is before the Stop Time in df1 I would want deltatime of 0. For instance:

df1

```
Stop Time                 Site
 2023-10-17 20:10:00.310      P2
 2023-10-17 21:20:00.440      P1
 2023-10-17 23:30:00.200      P2
 2023-10-18 00:00:00.190      P1
 2023-10-18 01:00:00.130      P1
 2023-10-18 02:00:00.500      P2
 2023-10-18 03:00:00.480      P1
 2023-10-18 04:00:00.020      P2
 2023-10-18 05:00:00.000      P1
 2023-10-18 06:00:00.580      P2
```

df2

```
Start Time               Site
2023-10-17 16:00:00.190      SMR
2023-10-17 17:05:00.050      SMR
2023-10-17 19:10:00.550      SMR
2023-10-17 21:40:00.530      SMR
2023-10-17 22:21:00.180      SMR
2023-10-18 05:21:00.090      SMR
2023-10-18 09:15:00.360      SMR
2023-10-18 11:54:00.160      SMR
```

This should generate a new df with

```
dt      Site
 0          P2
 0          P2
 0          P2
 30 min      P2
 1hr 11 min  P2
...
```

This dataset is `df1.shape[0] * df2.shape[0]` entries long.

This is just for entry 1 of df1 where the first 3 entries in df2 are BEFORE df1[1] so I get 0, and then I have the delta time going forward.
Again I can do this row by row but I'm sure there's a pandas was to do this quickly.

As an added step, I'd like to find just the minimum delta time (including the zero) for each entry in df1 against ALL entries in df2... this would another resulting df.

Thx,

Comment: You're asking two different questions here, I would suggest breaking this into 2 questions adding the expected output for your "added step" as well

Comment: How do you calculate 30min and 1h11min? Please break down the detail of the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the problem but you can use `numpy` broadcasting to compute the difference efficiently:

```
arr = df2['Start Time'].values - df1['Stop Time'].values[:, None]
arr[arr <= np.timedelta64(0)] = np.datetime64('NaT')
diff = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df1.index, columns=df2.index)
```

Output:

```
>>> diff
    0   1   2                      3                      4                      5                      6                      7
0 NaT NaT NaT 0 days 01:30:00.220000 0 days 02:10:59.870000 0 days 09:10:59.780000 0 days 13:05:00.050000 0 days 15:43:59.850000
1 NaT NaT NaT 0 days 00:20:00.090000 0 days 01:00:59.740000 0 days 08:00:59.650000 0 days 11:54:59.920000 0 days 14:33:59.720000
2 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 05:50:59.890000 0 days 09:45:00.160000 0 days 12:23:59.960000
3 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 05:20:59.900000 0 days 09:15:00.170000 0 days 11:53:59.970000
4 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 04:20:59.960000 0 days 08:15:00.230000 0 days 10:54:00.030000
5 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 03:20:59.590000 0 days 07:14:59.860000 0 days 09:53:59.660000
6 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 02:20:59.610000 0 days 06:14:59.880000 0 days 08:53:59.680000
7 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 01:21:00.070000 0 days 05:15:00.340000 0 days 07:54:00.140000
8 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 00:21:00.090000 0 days 04:15:00.360000 0 days 06:54:00.160000
9 NaT NaT NaT                    NaT                    NaT                    NaT 0 days 03:14:59.780000 0 days 05:53:59.580000

>>> diff.min(axis=1)
0   0 days 01:30:00.220000
1   0 days 00:20:00.090000
2   0 days 05:50:59.890000
3   0 days 05:20:59.900000
4   0 days 04:20:59.960000
5   0 days 03:20:59.590000
6   0 days 02:20:59.610000
7   0 days 01:21:00.070000
8   0 days 00:21:00.090000
9   0 days 03:14:59.780000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: `diff.mask(diff==np.timedelta64(0))` is no longer necessary since I use `NaT` instead of `pd.Timestamp(0)` to mask the negative difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the cartesian product in pandas:

```
# First merge the dfs with 'cross' to generate all combinations of df1 and df2

out = d1[['Stop Time', 'Site']].merge(d2[['Start Time']], how='cross')


# Then convert the columns to Datetime and calculate TimeDelta
out['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(out['Stop Time']) - pd.to_datetime(out['Start Time'])

# Then convert negative values to 0 and divide by 60 to get the minutes
out['dt'] = np.round(np.where(out['dt'].dt.total_seconds()<0, 0, out['dt'].dt.total_seconds()/60),2)
>>>out.head()

Stop Time   Site    Start Time  dt
0   2023-10-17 20:10:00.310 P2  2023-10-17 16:00:00.190 250.0
1   2023-10-17 20:10:00.310 P2  2023-10-17 17:05:00.050 185.0
2   2023-10-17 20:10:00.310 P2  2023-10-17 19:10:00.550 60.0
3   2023-10-17 20:10:00.310 P2  2023-10-17 21:40:00.530 0.0
4   2023-10-17 20:10:00.310 P2  2023-10-17 22:21:00.180 0.0
```

For your second query, you can just groupby by stop time and get the minimum delta:

```
>>> out.groupby(['Stop Time', 'Start Time'])[['dt']].min()
```